# With mahout Taste library how can i get neighbors and similarity for fiven userid

Tags: mahout

I am using mahout taste library for reccomendation engine..I get reccomendations for userid but not proper results..so i need to know its neighbores and similarity value..how can i get it.

With advance thanks,
laxmi.P

Comment: You might want to invest some time writing clearer and more thorough questions. What do you mean "not proper results"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to compute the similarity between to users, then you do not need a `Recommender`. Use an implementation of `UserNeighborhood`, along with your `UserSimilarity` with your `DataModel`, to just compute a neighborhood.

Comment: :i need to see the similarity value too